# Google Analytics - Custom Variable combine with User ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, tableau-api

I want to send out newsletters which are linking to my website. On my website, all content except the landing page from the NL is protected by authentication login.

I want to build a detailed customer journey for all recipients and all logged in website users.

I think I will need the following two things:
1. **Custom Variable** for the NL with an individual ID
2. **User ID** for the authentication login

Am I right? AND, the most important thing, how can I **combine** this two values correctly?

Please note: I don't want to analyze personal information as it's not allowed in GA. But what I want to do is that the data from GA is exported via the GA API to Tableau to make reports for every user. Do you think I could make this in that way?

Answer (score 0):

The userID is not a [queryable dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets). Probably what you want to do is create a [user scoped custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#example-user).

You can send in a [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) as follows:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', {
  userId: USER_ID
});

ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension15':  USER_ID + NL
});
```

And then you can query the custom dimension with the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) with `dimensions=ga:dimension15`.